# jQuery UI autocomplete on multiple rows created with .clone() method

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, clone

I'm almost new to jQuery... I found some tutorials/posts explaining
1. how to clone a table row (useful for inserting invoice details): http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validate-will-not-submit-to-server
2. how to use the jQuery UI autocomplete with PHP and MySQL (useful for retrieving products from a db table and avoid typing everything): http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

Well, 'til now I can clone table rows and I can get autocmplete work on the first row, but problems arise when I add another row and I expect the autocomplete work there, too
I found a thread here in StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492198/jquery-auto-complete-for-dynamically-generated-textboxes), but had no luck of applying to my case...

And now, the code:

The HTML part

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" class="grid" id="details">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Codice</th>
   <th scope="col">Nome</th>
   <th scope="col">Quantità</th>
   <th scope="col">Unità di misura</th>
   <th scope="col">Costo U.</th>
   <th scope="col">Totale</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr id="row_0" class="iterable">
   <td><input type="text" name="det_sku_0" id="det_sku_0" class="sku required" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="det_name_0" id="det_name_0" class="name required" /></td>
   <td><input name="det_quantity_0" id="det_quantity_0" type="text" class="required" /></td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td><input name="det_price_0" id="det_price_0" type="text" class="required" />€</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<ul>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove" class="icons icon-0">Rimuovi ultima riga</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add" class="icons icon-new">Aggiungi riga</a></li>
 <li><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Salva tutto" /></li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery part

```
    function addrow(destination) {
     rowcount = parseInt(parent_row.attr('id').replace('row_',''))+1;
     clonecopy = destination.clone(true);
     clonecopy.attr("class","iterable");
     // update numerical suffixes
     clonecopy.attr("id","row_"+rowcount);
     clonecopy.find('.sku, .name').val('');
     clonecopy.find("input[name^='det_sku']").attr({
      "name": "det_sku_"+rowcount,
      "id": "det_sku_"+rowcount
     });
     clonecopy.find("input[name^='det_name']").attr({
      "name": "det_name_"+rowcount,
      "id": "det_name_"+rowcount
     });
     clonecopy.find("select[name^='det_quantity']").attr({
      "name": "det_quantity_"+rowcount,
      "id": "det_quantity_"+rowcount
     });
     clonecopy.find("select[name^='det_price']").attr({
      "name": "det_price"+rowcount,
      "id": "det_price"+rowcount
     });
     clonecopy.insertAfter(destination);
     $('#det_arrayitems').val(rowcount);
    }

$("#add").click(function() {
        parent_row = $('#details tbody>tr:last');
        addrow(parent_row);
    });    

$('input.sku').autocomplete({
     source: "../json/products.php",
     minLength: 2,
     select: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).parent().siblings().children('input.name').val(ui.item.name);
     }
    })
```

I also tried this (and a couple of other ideas), but no luck

```
$("#add").live("click", function() {
 parent_row = $('#details tbody>tr:last');
 addrow(parent_row);
 $('input.sku').autocomplete({
  source: "../json/products.php",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
   $('input.sku').parent().siblings().children('input.name').val(ui.item.name);
  }
 })
});
```

Please, can you help me?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I had to put the autocomplete inside the addrow function and remove the word "true" from the .clone(true) according (and thanks) to this: [JQuery: How to clone autocomplete fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632212/jquery-how-to-clone-autocomplete-fields)

```
function addrow(destination) {
 rowcount = parseInt(parent_row.attr('id').replace('row_',''))+1;
 clonecopy = destination.clone();
 clonecopy.attr("class","iterable");
 // update numerical suffixes
 clonecopy.attr("id","row_"+rowcount);
 clonecopy.find('.sku, .name').val('');
 clonecopy.find("input[name^='det_sku']").attr({
  "name": "det_sku_"+rowcount,
  "id": "det_sku_"+rowcount
 }).autocomplete({       
  source: "../json/products.php",       
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
   $(this).parent().siblings().children('input.name').val(ui.item.name);       
  }
 });
 clonecopy.find("input[name^='det_name']").attr({
  "name": "det_name_"+rowcount,
  "id": "det_name_"+rowcount
 });

 clonecopy.find("select[name^='det_quantity']").attr({
  "name": "det_quantity_"+rowcount,
  "id": "det_quantity_"+rowcount
 });
 clonecopy.find("select[name^='det_price']").attr({
  "name": "det_price"+rowcount,
  "id": "det_price"+rowcount
 });
 clonecopy.insertAfter(destination);
 $('#det_arrayitems').val(rowcount);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar where I have a div that holds all the rows, and eact input field in a row has a rel tag with the base part of it's name and ID and then on the click to add a row I call the following:

```
 $("#addChain").click(function() {  
         var index = $("#chainHolder").children().length + 1;  
        $("#chainHolder").children(":first").clone().each(function() {  
       $(this).find(":input").each(function() {  
                $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("rel")+"["+index+"]");  
                $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("rel")+"["+index+"]");  
            });  
             $(this).children(":first").val(index);  
        }).appendTo("#chainHolder");  
    });
```

Comment: Uhm... I miss the Autocomplete part here... I have no difficulties in adding rows to a table with jQuery, but in making the Autocomplete work for every created row

Answer (score 0):

Create button with class name of addmore, then on the button click call the following method. Please form your table row like this below and finally append that formed html to your table.

```
//adds extra table rows
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
     html = '<tr>';
     html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
     html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
     html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
     html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
     html += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
     html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
     html += '</tr>';
     $('table').append(html);
     i++;
 });
```

Following script will do the deletion part... For delete create button with class name of delete.

```
//deletes the selected table rows
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
   $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
   $('#check_all').prop("checked", false); 
});
```

I had made simple tutorial for sample invoice system with all the functionalities you mentioned right from

1. multiple table row add and delete
2. multiple autocomplete and lot

[Invoice System Using jQuery AutoComplete](http://Invoice%20System%20Using%20jQuery%20AutoComplete)

Comment: your link "Invoice System Using jQuery AutoComplete" is not setup